# Is there any Modularity method for overlapping community detection in Python?

Tags: python, graph, igraph, modularity

I'm working on an overlapping community detection code in python and to evaluate my results, I tried using igraph modularity method. But I was unable to figure out how to make it work with my overlapping algorithm results.
So is there any Modularity method for overlapping communities in Python?

The output of my community detection code is an array of tuples in which the first number in tuple #k shows that how much node #k belongs to the first community and  the second number in tuple #k shows that how much node #k belongs to the second community. For example if a tuple in the array is (0,1), it means the corresponding node only belongs to the second community, and if a tuple is (0.7,0.3), it means the node belongs to both communities. (Of course I'm open to change my output to other formats, if needed.)

Comment: I am searching for the same thing but unfortunately I didn't find a code... However, I found that modularity can be used with overlapping communities with some modifications, it is mentioned in "Overlapping modularity at the critical point of k-clique percolation".

Answer (score 0):

There is [`cdlib.evaluation.modularity_overlap`](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.2/reference/eval/cdlib.evaluation.modularity_overlap.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35492952)

Comment: @E.Zeytinci while it may be a lazy answer it does not meet the test of being a link-only non-answer. Even without the link, the method name is still being provided.

Comment: It may be true but I still agree with the idea in this sentence: "Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes". We can't find any details about this method in the answer if the linked page changes.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci 1) google is a thing. if it moves, you can google. 2) If official docs disappear off the face of the net, there are bigger problems. 3) https://web.archive.org/web/20240109003954/https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.2/reference/eval/cdlib.evaluation.modularity_overlap.html

Comment: If you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, you can see this description: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there." I'm just trying to stick to the rules. I cannot see any description in this answer.

Comment: IMO, It is obvious to deduce that the link itself leads to the answer.